# Is it possible to run bazel build with a increased io-niceness value?

Tags: bazel

I would like to run `bazel` and all of its subprocesses at a higher IO-nice-ness level.

How can I achieve that?

Answer (score 1):

For your original question regarding CPU niceness; what I ended up doing was to write a tiny wrapper that calls the original bazel binary. I have it stored at`~/.local/bin/bazel`, which is early in my $PATH.

```
#!/usr/bin/env sh

exec nice /path/to/original/bazel/binary "$@"
```

Make sure it's in your $PATH (`which -a bazel` will show you if it is) and to make it executable (`chmod +x path/to/wrapper/script`)

Comment: Thank you, that's probably going to work.

Answer (score -1):

You can use the `bazel --io_nice_level=<your nice value here>` option

Careful it's a startup option, so you need to pass that flag before the bazel action:

```
bazel --io_nice_level=8 build //...
```

Comment: That's changing the IO niceness. The term "niceness" without any qualifier refers to the SCHED_OTHER niceness which affects competition for CPU resources instead.

Comment: Thank you! I'll modify the question so that it's still relevant.   Is there a corresponding flag for CPU resource niceness?

Comment: Not that I've seen. I clicked on the question hoping to find one :) I've run the `bazel` client command under `nice(1)` (or `chrt`) like `nice -n 5 bazel build //...` to get a similar effect. However, you have to do that for the first `bazel` command which starts the server, which is error-prone.